# Is there a way to remove two numbers not affecting others?

Tags: php, arrays, shuffle

The code is giving the following output and each time, it will give a different output.

Is there any way to remove to 2 numbers for example 15 and 60, so that other numbers are not effected they remain the same?

I have tried but could not get the desired result.

Any help or any idea how to do this?

```
<?php

$arr = array();

for ($i = 1; $i < 82; $i++) {
    $arr[] = $i;
}

shuffle($arr);
$lines = array_chunk($arr, 9);

echo "<table>";

foreach ($lines as $key => $line) {
    echo "<tr>";
    for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($line); $i++) {
        echo "<td align='right'>" . $line[$i] . "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
?>




 Out put

 52 67  5   44  76  49  1   27  28
 73 33  19  66  4   14  63  45  62
 26 75  50  80  70  38  12  54  78
 9  69  36  32  2   7   56  11  51
 40 20  22  15  60  65  31  41  77
 57 29  34  79  68  23  18  71  39
 42 10  72  17  81  30  35  48  47
 37 59  53  6   3   55  13  46  58
 61 25  24  64  74  43  21  8   16
```

Comment: Just do `$arr = array_diff($arr, [15, 60]);` before your shuffle call?!

Comment: what do you mean by `so that other numbers are not effected they remain the same`? Do you want the 2 removed numbers to cause empty spaces at the end, or have the empty spaces where they would have been?

Comment: I want the empty spaces where the numbers are deleted and all other numbers remain the same.

Comment: You could replace the required numbers with spaces when displaying the line. As already suggested, you can use an array function - this time:`in_array($line[$i] , array(15, 60))` to determine whether to show the number or spaces. You only have to change your  `output` routine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

Just place the code before your `shuffle()` call. Basically first we create an array of patterns, by looping through all numbers, which we want to extract from the list, with [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php).

The pattern basically has two [anchors](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.anchors.php) to match the numbers fully in your array and not only partially (E.g. `2` will not match `24`, but it will match `2`).

With the created pattern array we just use [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) to replace the numbers in your array with an empty string.

```
$numbers = [15, 60];
$pattern = array_map(function($v){
    return "/^$v$/";
}, $numbers);
$arr = preg_replace($pattern, "", $arr);
```